# Facebook Posts and Multiple Actions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can you post multiple actions (I want to do two) with a wall post using the Facebook Graph API?  If so what is the format that should be used for the actions string.  I can't get this to work for the life of me.

[This piece of documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) describes the parameter as a array of objects containing the name and link. I used json to do this however I can only successfully do one action link and not two.

Comment: What do you mean multiple actions? Multiple wall posts?

Comment: The fbdevwiki link didn't work for me.

Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609074/multiple-fb-dialog-action-links

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about the custom app-pecified links displayed in the wall post. No, facebook allows only 1, and tha'ts how the structure of facebook wall post is.

Answer (score 0):

there is written here [http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui#method:_.27feed.27](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui#method%3a_.27feed.27)  that only one action link allowed